# Alpaca Forms validation show error message only after user leaves field (leaves the field)

Tags: javascript, alpacajs

All the fields marked required are in red when the form loads since they are blank. How do I change this so that they only turn red (check validation) if/when someone leaves a particular field. This is specific to Alpaca forms.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#form").alpaca({
                "schema": {
                    "title":"User Feedback",
                    "description":"What do you think about Alpaca?",
                    "type":"object",
                    "properties": {
                        "volunteer_name": {
                            "type":"string",
                            "title":"Name of Civic Tutor",
                            "required":true
                        },
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 6):

Oh, there's actually a very simple solution to this. Just add a 
"options": {"hideInitValidationError":true,....} to your form.